# PDF output works in an embedded window, but not in the separate window

Tags: texstudio, viewers

I have the following problem. When I want to display the PDF output in the separate window it doesn't work, however when I just choose the embedded window it works. I attach the screenshot of the settings

[image: Settings]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your title and your actual question seem to be the exact opposite.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh, thank you for the greeting and thank you for the comment, I mistyped this=)